# Put every object in a specified bucket

Tags: javascript, mapreduce

I have this array of objects:

```js
const dataset = [
  {name: 'Paul', age: 10},
  {name: 'Marcus', age: 5},
  {name: 'Jennifer', age: 1},
  {name: 'Linda', age: 53},
  {name: 'Mary', age: 4},
  {name: 'Rose', age: 40},
  {name: 'Peter', age: 2},
]
```

and an array of ranges:

```js
const buckets = [[0, 10], [10, 20], [20, 30], [30, 60]]
```

This is what I would like to get:

```js
const result = {
  "0-10": {
    res: [{name: 'Marcus', age: 5}, {name: 'Jennifer', age: 1}, {name: 'Mary', age: 4}, {name: 'Peter', age: 2}], 
    count: 4
  },
  "10-20": {res: [{name: 'Paul', age: 10}], count: 1},
  "20-30": {res: [], count: 0},
  "30-60": {res: [{name: 'Linda', age: 53}, {name: 'Rose', age: 40}], count: 2},
}
```

So I would like to get an object where each key is the bucket range (as string) and each value is an object that contains two info: `res` should be an array of people whose `age` is inside that bucket (`min <= age < max`) and `count` is the lenght of that array.

Here is my code:

```js
const res = buckets.reduce((acc, bucketExtent) => {
        const keyBucket = `${bucketExtent[0]}-${bucketExtent[1]}`
        const people = dataset.filter(
          (s) => s['age'] >= bucketExtent[0] && s['age'] < bucketExtent[1]
        )
        acc[keyBucket] = {
          res: people,
          count: people.length,
        }
        return acc
      }, {})
```

It works but there is a smarter way? I prefer not to loop everytime the `dataset` array because it will be very large

Comment: That `count` property hurts my brain.. why?

Comment: It's only an example

Answer (score 2):

From a short review;

- You are definitely looping indeed over every entry 4 times
- This belongs in a well named function
- Other than that, it is very straight forward and understandable

I was thinking that people don't live all that long, you could easily build a lookup table for every possible age. This could speed this up quite a bit.

So something like this;

```js
const dataset = [
  {name: 'Paul', age: 10},
  {name: 'Marcus', age: 5},
  {name: 'Jennifer', age: 1},
  {name: 'Linda', age: 53},
  {name: 'Mary', age: 4},
  {name: 'Rose', age: 40},
  {name: 'Peter', age: 2},
]

const buckets = [[0, 10], [10, 20], [20, 30], [30, 60]]

function createAgeBuckets(dataset, buckets){
  const start = 0, end = 1;
  const out = {}, ages = [];
  
  //Create age range
  for(const bucket of buckets){
    bucketRange = `${bucket[start]}-${bucket[end]}`;
    out[bucketRange] = {res: [], count: 0}; 
    for(let age = bucket[start]; age < bucket[end];age++){
      ages[age] = out[bucketRange];
    }
  }

  //Create bucketses
  dataset.forEach(person => {
    ages[person.age].res.push(person);
    ages[person.age].count++;
  });

  return out;
}

console.log(createAgeBuckets(dataset, buckets));
```

Answer (score 1):

One  approach for reducing the amount of nested loops was to create kind of an **`usher`** or ***attendant*** functionality which takes/reads a number value and immediately, due to simple min/max value comparison, returns the correct bucket key.

Since one has to preprocess this `usher` from a list of (bucket) ranges, one in addition can create (within the same process) each possible bucket's default entry (key and value) as kind of an `index` which then is part of the start value of the later data reducing/collecting process.

```js
function createBucketConfig(bucketList) {
  const {

    index, // bucket index.
    assignmentList,

  } = bucketList.reduce((config, [min, max]) => {

    const bucketKey = `${ min }-${ max }`;
    const assignment = num => (num < max) && (num >= min) && bucketKey;

    config.index[bucketKey] = { res: [], count: 0 }; // default bucket value.
    config.assignmentList.push(assignment);

    return config;

  }, { index: {}, assignmentList: [] });

  const usher = num => {
    let bucketKey;
    assignmentList.some(assignment => {
      bucketKey = assignment(num);
      return !!bucketKey;
    });
    return bucketKey || 'out-of-range';
  };

  return {
    index, // bucket index.
    usher, // bucket usher.
  }
}


const dataset = [
  {name: 'Paul', age: 10},
  {name: 'Marcus', age: 5},
  {name: 'Jennifer', age: 1},
  {name: 'Linda', age: 53},
  {name: 'Mary', age: 4},
  {name: 'Rose', age: 40},
  {name: 'Peter', age: 2},
];
const buckets = [[0, 10], [10, 20], [20, 30], [30, 60]];


const { index, usher } = createBucketConfig(buckets);

console.log('usher(0) :', usher(0));
console.log('usher(5) :', usher(5));
console.log('usher(10) :', usher(10));
console.log('usher(11) :', usher(11));
console.log('usher(19) :', usher(19));
console.log('usher(20) :', usher(20));
console.log('usher(29) :', usher(29));
console.log('usher(30) :', usher(30));
console.log('usher(60) :', usher(60));

console.log('default bucket index ... ', index);

console.log(
  'reduced into buckets via preprocessed bucket config  ...',

  dataset.reduce((collector, data) => {
    const { usher, index } = collector;
    const bucketKey = usher(data.age);

    const bucket = index[bucketKey] || (index[bucketKey] = { res: [] });

    bucket.res.push(data);
    bucket.count = bucket.res.length;

    return collector;

  }, createBucketConfig(buckets)).index
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @whitecircle ... are there any questions left regarding the above approach?